# draw circle in canvas with click option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I write this javascript code :

```
<script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
        var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
        var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

        function handleMouseDown(e) {
            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
            $("#downlog").html("Down: " + mouseX + " / " + mouseY);
        }

        $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
            handleMouseDown(e);
        });

    </script>
```

in this code , I detect a coordinate with mouse click .
I want draw a circle around the this coordinate that when I click on circle , do something (for ex. open google.com)

note : I do this with jquery in html 4 and with area map , but I do not have any idea in canvas .

Comment: I would add Raphael.js to your stack of JS libraries.  It makes drawing really easy.  http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: So you're trying to see if a user clicked in your circle?

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell if you want to draw a circle, detect a mouse click in a circle or both.

Draw a circle:

```
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

//Draw a circle around a mouse click
//ctx.arc(x-position, y-position, radius, start-angle, end-angle);
ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Detect a  mouse click within a circle:

```
//circleX and circleY are the coordinats of the center
var y = mouseY - circleY;
var x = mouseX - circleX;
var dist = Math.sqrt(y*y + x*x);

if (dist < circleRadius) {
  // Do whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 70;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
```